# What makes longitudinal waves work?

Tags: waves, pressure, air

I am quite confused by what makes a wavefront that is part of the compression (line A) turn back towards the rarefaction area. Lets say that the sound is propagating left to right in the image:

[image: Particle A changing direction of movement backwards]

What force exactly makes A go backwards suddenly? The compression was made by an external force towards the right and the wavefront B is still going in that direction. I have 2 guesses:

1. The air column above the particle A, due to it's weight and gravity, is squeezing downwards on it causing it to go somewhere and it can't go any other way but left. (going from high towards the low pressure area due to gravity basically). But why doesn't the air above the rarefaction simply fill out the space?
2. The molecular bonds of air in the wavefront "B" that were squeezed/compressed are now uncompressing, springing back exerting force on particle A towards the left. (is this what air elasticity" is?)

EDIT: I found this somewhere on the site, it might be related to the answer (or part of the answer at least):

> The other weird thing about the animation is that the molecules stop
> moving and turn around without colliding with anything! It should be
> obvious that in a real gas made of electrically neutral particles,
> there is no long-distance force that would cause this to happen, and a
> moving particle would not change direction unless it actually collided
> with another particle.

Is collision with other particles the reason for particle A in the picture going back towards rarefaction? And the only reason that low pressure area gets filled up is random "trial and error" of particles bouncing off of each other?

Comment: Doesn't A go back because of vacuum? i was taught that when the string vibrates, if it goes towards the right, then the air molecules are displaced forward, i.e, towards the right. Then the string returns back to its normal position and goes left which causes some space between the air molecules and the string. so the air molecules now go back towards the left to fill that space.

Comment: It might be, but my question is WHY would they go towards the vacuum? Vacuum doesn't exert an attractive force on them, so what exactly are the mechanics of air pressure that make the air redistribute from high pressure to low pressure area? Especially when it's moving towards left and the air next to it is not only not pushing it that way (as far as I can tell) but it's even going the opposite direction...

Comment: Suppose we have two small pistons in A and B, the front the sound wave will compress the air between the two pistons: A moves towards B, the pressure increases, when the wave is midway between A and B which is still at rest, piston A stops and at this moment begins the reverse movement which is the consequence of the increase in pressure between the two pistons.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bcqp6t4ybxU

Comment: Thanks. If I understood the gentlemen bellow, in rigid bodies like this slinky in the demonstration, it will be the elastic force that forces the slinky backwards. The piston tension that you are describing is stretched/squeezed molecular bonds that want to spring back. Where as in the air it is the area of high frequency collisions that doesn't really have a force pulling it back, but still does disperse due to pure probability. Right?

Comment: The sound wave equation can be described in terms of D'Alembertian (pressure)=0, i.e. there is a region of overpressure and a region of depression with respect to the pressure of the medium, or else in terms of density (n),D'Alembertian (density)=0, ....

Comment: Basically, there is no probability, it is a consequence to effect: for a difference in pressure, density,.., the molecules move towards the depression (or towards the less dense medium) to balance the forces (df=-pdS), the pressures, the densities,....

Comment: Gravity is irrelevant. Astronauts on the ISS can speak to one another.

Comment: @Tiler What exactly makes the molecules go towards the rarefaction zone if not higher probability of collision towards the high density zone and lower probability of collision towards the low density zone, which in turn as I understood it has the effect of them spreading out within it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we have a sound wave in air, we have a wave movement combined with the normal random movement of the molecules in the air. The random movement results in collision between molecules and between molecules and anything else. The pressure is the average force (per unit area) exerted by the effect of all these collision.

The lines in your diagram do not correspond to actual air molecules. When a line is in its central position it shows that the average position of air molecules in that region is where it normally would be, and when a line is moved to the right it shows that the average position of molecules is moved to the right. Note though that the movement of the line does not show how far the molecules have moved; it is only a representation.

Where the lines are closer together the pressure is higher, so the molecules they represent will undergo more collisions, which will on average push them away from each other, towards places there are fewer collisions (where the lines are further apart). Hence the lines can move backwards even if the next line is moving forwards; this just means that the molecules in that area have a net movement backwards, while the molecules ahead of them have a net movement forward. This will soon bring about a lower pressure in that place, but that won't be seen until a later snapshot.

Comment: Lovely explanation as well Peter, thanks a ton!
I have one more thing if you don't mind: does the compression area front form when the the surface of the object (lets say a cymbal) move through what was the average rate of collisions, pushing particles in the process but more importantly giving a more readily available surface to bounce off of? More like narrowing down the window of collision area rather than actively pushing the particles, if that makes sense? And then making a low collision probability area as it deforms back.

Comment: You don't get a sound from a cymbal surface that is not moving, so it is not just having a surface to bounce off. In the absence of the surface there would be collisions between air molecules and exchange of air particles, so a stationary surface would not change things much. However, when a cymbal moves into a volume its moving surface means molecules bounce off with a higher speed, which means there is higher pressure.

Comment: Ah, so it's the addition of the movement vectors of air particles that ultimately creates the high-density/pressure area. And probably fortified by the cymbal surface following through in the same direction, bouncing off again some of the particles that were accelerated in that direction yet have bounced backwards again?

Comment: But what's confusing to me is that the wave propagation in air, at the same conditions - has the same speed (as far as I've read). How can particles then gain speed from this, seems contradictory?

Comment: The energy in a sound wave is quite small, so it doesn't make much difference to the speed of the molecules. The speed of the *wave* is the speed this small difference gets passed on from molecule to molecule.

Comment: In the example of lets say a string vibrating at a fundamental frequency only, to simplify: if it a) vibrates at frequency F, with very high amplitude. and b) Vibrates at the same frequency F with very low amplitude. Wouldn't the speed of the string be higher in the case a, traveling the greater distance over the same period? And wouldn't that in turn get passed over to the particles thus making the wave faster/slower depending on the amplitude?

Comment: It's quite strange how the speed difference is significant enough to seriously rearrange them yet negligible enough so we don't even count it as a particle speed change.

Comment: When I say *quite* small - it takes about 1200 J of energy to raise the temperature of a cubic metre of air by 1 Kelvin. Sound energy of 0.001 J per second across a square metre is 90 dB - enough to cause hearing damage if it goes on for too long. The energy in the wave is spread across *many* molecules, so none of them get much faster except very close to the string

Answer (score 9):

Air molecules at standard temperature and pressure have a [mean free path between collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) of order $\rm 10^2 \ nm =10^{-7}\ m$.  An “ultrasonic” audio frequency might be about $10^5\rm \,Hz$. (Human hearing disappears for frequencies above about 20 kHz.) But with typical thermal speeds of $10^2\rm\,m/s$, the air molecules are colliding with each other billions of times per second.

The motion of an air molecule during a single rarefaction-to-rarefaction cycle of an ultrasonic sound wave is governed by many thousands of collisions. This is plenty of opportunities for a pressure differential to drive a particular molecule towards the low-pressure part of the sound wave, and plenty enough that the approximation of continuum motion is useful.

Comment: Ah, thank you Rob! So the only effect that gravity has on air distribution is the effect it has on the general density of air if I understand correctly? The rest is due to the higher probability of molecules to bounce into something in a high pressure part and go towards the low pressure one?

Comment: And when we send one pulse of compression through this random bouncing madness - we just add a vector in the direction of sound propagation to all these motions already there, and they, on average just start moving more towards that direction until they transfer that kinetic energy and over time randomly redistribute back into the rarefaction area?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Just so.

Comment: Do the molecular bonds in air play a role in this? I've heard of air elasticity here and there, but still don't understand how(and if) it applies to this scenario.

PS: You've already made my day, it was bugging me so much. :D

Comment: In an “ideal gas,” there are no “bonds” between molecules.

Comment: What does air elasticity refer to then? Sorry if it's a dumba*s question.

Comment: If you can’t find a satisfactory definition, I suggest you ask a follow-up question about that specifically.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will! Much appreciated. I'll look a bit for a day or two before asking.

Answer (score 1):

The basic mechanism behind a standard harmonic motion is having some quantity whose second derivative varies as a function of that quantity (in more complicated cases, it's a function of that quantity as well as others). This function is such that the derivative of the quantity is out of phase with the function and second derivative: the quantity will "overshoot" some equilibrium value, and move away from the equilibrium when it's at the equilibrium (i.e. have nonzero derivative when the function is zero). This "overshooting" is core to the wave phenomenon: the quantity will overshoot in one direction, be pulled back, and then come back to the equilibrium point, but now it has a nonzero derivative in the other direction and overshoots, back and forth.

Generally, the quantity is position, and then the second derivative is acceleration, which is proportional to force; that is, force is a function of position. In the case of a longitudinal wave, the quantity is density. Increasing the density increases the pressure, which increases the outward force, which increases the expansion rate, which decreases the density. However, the gas retains the expansion velocity even when it reaches the equilibrium pressure and no longer has an outward force, so it overshoots the equilibrium pressure and becomes rarified (low pressure).

Comment: So if I understood correctly, this confirms that higher density simply put increases the collision probability and the low density allows for an unobstructed propagation of the particles back into that area?
But the part that puzzles me is how (in case of longitudinal waves) does:
 ""the gas retains the expansion velocity even when it reaches the equilibrium pressure and no longer has an outward force, so it overshoots the equilibrium pressure and becomes rarified ""?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that even a single pulse, a single compression area would generate something quite like a standing wave, without even reflecting? THis is what it sounds like it would happen if the compression really had a tendency to come back into the rarefaction and becomes rarefied itself, only to have the process repeat again, at whatever intensity...